# Marginal structural model - help with some concepts

Tags: regression, causality, propensity-scores, marginal-model

I'm trying to gain some (deeper) understanding of MSM's - what exactly they are and when they might be appropriate to use.

Are my thoughts on the following correct (please feel free to correct any misunderstandings I have):

1. Any regression model specification that has a treatment or exposure as the only covariate of interest and includes a weights argument as a vector of the inverse of propensity scores, can essentially be called an MSM (and this is fundamentally different to a regression model that instead uses propensity scores as an additional covariate to adjust on).
2. Following on from 1. this suggests to me that MSM's are considerably more flexible than alternative causal inference approaches like g-computation/standardisation. Basically, as long as a regression model allows weights to be included you can use rather standard model machinery (e.g logistic regression) to calculate the propensity scores/weights and then fit the desired model (whether it be a glm, survival model, gee, etc) including the calculated weights.
3. MSM's aren't exclusively applicable in longitudinal situations that might suffer from time-varying confounding. They can also be used with cross-sectional data to estimate an ATE.

Thanks.

Comment: 3) Yes, that's true. 1) I also agree with that. Adding propensity-based feature into a regression _in addition_ to other confounders (and treatment) might be considered a doubly-robust model and should be somewhat equivalent to a regression on all confounders+treatment that is IP-weighted. 2) On the face of it, yes. Note that GEEs might even be superior to GLMs here since the weighted sample can artificially increase the sample size by adding dependent observation (e.g. $w_i=2$ basically adds $i$ twice to the data) so GEEs may lead to a better coverage of the 95% confidence intervals.